# Index of ListView is -1 before clearing it

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

In my WPF Application I have a ListView with a function running when the selection changes. After getting the index of the selected item, I want to clear the selection. But if I do this, `index` is always `-1` and not the index of the selected item.

This Code works:

```
        private void ListViewItems_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var index = ListViewItems.SelectedIndex;
            Note note = MainWindow.dBConnector.NotesList[index];
            ShowNote(note);
        }
```

But when I try to reset the selection at any time later on, the index is out of range (set to -1)

```
        private void ListViewItems_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //index is somehow here already -1
            var index = ListViewItems.SelectedIndex;

            //This causes a System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException (because there is no item at -1)
            Note note = MainWindow.dBConnector.NotesList[index];
            ShowNote(note);

            //This causes the error
            ListViewItems.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
```

I tried different methods to reset the selection, nothing changes. I even tried to reset the selection at a later point in the program, but nothing changes, index is always -1.

Why does this happen and how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically when you change your index to -1 it also fired your selection-changed event
then your index become -1

in your selection-changed event you should check if index is not equal to -1 i.e

```
private void ListViewItems_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(ListViewItems.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        var index = ListViewItems.SelectedIndex;
        Note note = MainWindow.dBConnector.NotesList[index];
        ShowNote(note);

        ListViewItems.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
}
```